# Why does $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I recently [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) a fact that surprised me:

The power set of the natural numbers is equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |\mathbb{R}|$.

I don't intuitively see why this is true. Can anyone explain why?

*Edit: duplicate has been found, please vote to close.*

Comment: $|\Bbb R|\geqslant \aleph_1$ is all you can say.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553526/the-set-of-real-numbers

Comment: Brad found a similar thread; I've voted to close mine.

Comment: @AustinMohr The other thread was particularly difficult to find. I'd rather leave this open, and let it be a duplicate linking to the other thread. Thus, the other thread becomes easier to find for other users.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: think of binary numbers between $0$ and $1$. What subset of $\mathbf N$ might you associate to the binary number $0.10101010101...$, say?

(There is a minor issue arising from the fact that rational numbers have two different binary expansions $(1=0.1111111...)$, but away from this countable set, this doesn't pose any problem.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\mathbb{Q}\simeq\mathbb{N}$ then you know $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})\simeq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. There is one construction of $\mathbb{R}$ which defines them as a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$. Thus there is an injection $\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$---inclusion. Here is an injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{R}$:

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and define $f(S)=\sum_{k\in S} 2^{-k}$. This is an injection. Now that $\mathbb{R}\simeq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ follows from Schroder-Bernstein.

Comment: ...What construction of $\mathbb{R}$ defines the reals as a subset of $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{Q}$? I've only seen the ones by Dedekind Cuts and Cauchy Sequences.

Comment: the dedekind cuts *is* that construction