# Cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

how to prove that $\#\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \#\mathbb{R}$? I'm thinking in associate a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ in a real number by the decimal representation, but i'm failed.

Comment: Try binary representation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The set of real numbers and power set of the natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553526/the-set-of-real-numbers-and-power-set-of-the-natural-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an injective map $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to\Bbb R$, showing $\#\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\le\#\Bbb R$:

$$S\mapsto \sum_{k\in S}3^{-k} $$

Here's an injective map $\Bbb R\to \mathcal P(\Bbb Q)$, showing $\#\Bbb R\le\#\mathcal P(\Bbb Q)$:

$$\alpha\mapsto \{\,x\in \Bbb Q\mid \alpha<x\,\}.$$

As $\#\Bbb N=\#\Bbb Q$, the result follows.