# Proof equivalence of sets' power.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that powers are equivavalent.

$$\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\times Q} \times  \mathbb{N} \sim R^Q$$

Well, $\mathbb{Q} \sim \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{N}$.

We now have to prove this
$$\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \times  \mathbb{N} \sim R^\mathbb{N}$$

What to do next? Probably use cantor-bernstein theorem??

Comment: If you can use the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, then yes.

Comment: @HanulJeon, can you help me to do it? So I need to find 2 injections from left to the right and from right to the left.

Comment: What is $R$ in your statement? Do you know that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $R$ are equipotent?

Comment: Relevant: [The set of real numbers and power set of the natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553526/53976)

Comment: Is this true? If $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}\sim\mathbb R$, then this question is asking about $\mathbb R\times\mathbb N\sim\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. (I'm assuming the $R$ in your question is the set of real numbers)