# Cardinality of power set of $\mathbb N$ is equal to cardinality of $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that;

> The cardinality of power set of $\mathbb N$ is equal to cardinality of $\mathbb R$

I need a reference or proof outline. I looked up but didn't find results

thanks.

Comment: $\operatorname{card} \mathbb{R} = \operatorname{card} [0,1]$, now consider the binary representation of $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: To expand on Ross's answer: The set of functions $f:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ is in bijection with $P(\Bbb N)$. This is because given some $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ one can assign to each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ either $1$ if $n \in S$ or $0$ otherwise . This binary sequence is uniquely specified by the subset. But these sequences are precisely the binary representations of the numbers in the unit interval.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}$?  What have you tried? There are definitions that make this effectively trivial, and without knowing more about what your application is and _why_ you need the proof, it's difficult to helpfully answer the question.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553526/the-set-of-real-numbers
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679397/what-is-bigger-p-mathbbn-or-mathbbr
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209396/is-2-mathbbn-mathbbr
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658112/why-does-mathbbr-have-the-same-cardinality-as-mathcalp-mathbbn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: think of an element of $P(\Bbb N)$ as corresponding to a binary expansion-for a given subset $A$, let $x=\sum_{i \in A} 2^{-i}$ This gives you (almost) a bijection between $P(\Bbb N)$ and $[0,1]$

Comment: I don't understand why this is even a map. is there a typo? If not please explain more

Comment: You correspond a subset $A$ of the naturals with a binary expansion.  If $7 \in A$, you include $2^{-7}$ in the sum.  This gives you a real.  As the whole set (assuming you don't think $0 \in \Bbb N$) sums to $1$, nothing is greater.

Comment: Isn't any $x$ like that a rational number? is this what you mean by (almost)? any hint for how to fix this?

Comment: No, most subsets don't have any pattern, so will correspond to an irrational.  The (almost) was referring to the ambiguity of rational expansions-$0.1_2=0.0\overline 1_2$.  Since this is only countably many it is easy to handle.  The idea that most subsets are not only irrational, but not describable, is a big one.  There are only countably many descriptions of subsets, but there are uncountably many subsets, so most of them cannot be described.

Comment: I'm curious to know why the countable subset of $P(\Bbb N)$ is negligible. Is it the same as showing, for example, $\Bbb R\cong \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @Vim: Yes. You can show that a cocountable subset of a set of cardinality continuum also has cardinality continuum. Even without the axiom of choice!

Answer (score 26):

**I. There is an injection $f:P(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb R,$ that is, $|P(\mathbb N)|\le|\mathbb R|.$**

**Proof.** For $S\subseteq\mathbb N$ define $f(S)=\sum_{n\in S}10^{-n}.$

**II. There is an injection $g:\mathbb R\to P(\mathbb N),$ that is, $|\mathbb R|\le|P(\mathbb N)|.$**

**Proof.** Fix an enumeration $\mathbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ of the set $\mathbb Q$ of all rational numbers, and define $g(x)=\{n:q_n\lt x\}.$

The equality $|P(\mathbb N)|=|\mathbb R|,$ that is, the existence of a bijection between $P(\mathbb N)$ and $\mathbb R,$ follows from I and II by virtue of the [Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem). Since I can't tell from your question if you are familiar with that theorem, I will now give a proof.

**III. Lemma ([Knaster–Tarski Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem)). If a function $\varphi:P(A)\to P(A)$ satisfies the condition
$$X\subseteq Y\implies\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(Y)$$
for all $X,Y\subseteq A,$ then $\varphi(S)=S$ for some $S\subseteq A.$**

**Proof.** Let $\mathcal F=\{X:X\subseteq\varphi(X)\}$ and let $S=\bigcup\mathcal F.$ First note that, if $X\in\mathcal F,$ then $X\subseteq S$ and $X\subseteq\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(S).$ Since every member of $\mathcal F$ is a subset of $\varphi(S),$ it follows that $S=\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq\varphi(S),$ that is, $S\in\mathcal F.$ From $S\in\mathcal F$ it follows that $\varphi(S)\in\mathcal F,$ whence $\varphi(S)\subseteq S,$ and so $\varphi(S)=S.$

**IV. Theorem (Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein). If there are injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A,$ then there is a bijection between $A$ and $B.$**

**Proof.** Define a function $\varphi:P(A)\to P(A)$ by setting
$$\varphi(X)=A\setminus g[B\setminus f[X]]$$
for $X\subseteq A,$ and observe that $X\subseteq Y\subseteq A\implies\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(Y).$ By the lemma, there is a set $S\subseteq A$ such that $\varphi(S)=S,$ that is, $g[B\setminus f[S]]=A\setminus S.$ Thus, $f$ maps $S$ bijectively onto $f[S],$ and $g$ maps $B\setminus f[S]$ bijectively onto $A\setminus S,$ so there is a bijection between $A$ and $B.$

Comment: Fantastic answer. Clear as crystal.

Comment: Brilliantly done (+1)

Comment: To me, this is much better than the well-known proof using two-sided sequences. It's really satisfying :) But I guess I can never even think of the construction of $\varphi$ by myself btw.

Comment: @Hermis14 Some proofs require a tricky definition. Step IV here is not one of them; the function $\varphi$ is what it plainly needs to be. The set $X$ is mapped to $f[X]$, so $B\setminus f[X]$ must be mapped to $A\setminus X$, but is in fact mapped to $g[B\setminus f[X]]$. This means that $X$ must be chosen so that $$A\setminus X=g[B\setminus f[X]],$$ that is, $$X=A\setminus g[B\setminus f[X]].$$ In other words, $X$ must be a fixed point of the function $$\varphi(X)=A\setminus g[B\setminus f[X]].$$

Comment: It is still a tricky idea for me but your explanation made the setting much more reasonable and plausible. Thank you, bof.

Answer (score 2):

Imitate/replicate Cantor's diagonal.

Assume P (N) is countable and that we can index each subset as $A_i $ for some natural $i $.

Now consider the set $B =\{n \in \mathbb N| n \not \in A_n  \} $.  In other words create a new set by  going through the sets $A_i $. if $i \in A_i $ exclude it.  If $i \not \in A_i$ include it.

The resulting set will be distinct from all $A_i $ which means our indexing was not surjective which means no injective map from the naturals to P (N) exist, and P (N) is not countable.

=====

As Asaf Karagila points out this answer oversimplifies and merely shows that P(N) is uncountable but not that it has the cardinality of the reals.

On the other hand, I wouldn't say my answer doesn't address the question "at all".

As my argument replicates Cantors diagonals we can continue to conclude the same results as Cantors diagonal would conclude.

$P(\mathbb N) \cong \times_{\mathbb N}\{0,1\}$ via mapping $A \subset \mathbb N \rightarrow (x_1, x_2, x_3,..... )$ where $x_i = 1$ if $i \in A$ and $x_i = 0$ if $i \not \in A$.  (And by Cantor's diagonal both are uncountable-- although that was never asked to be shown apparently.)

And $|  \times_{\mathbb N}\{0,1\} | = |\mathbb R|$ is a standard analysis result.

$ \times_{\mathbb N}\{0,1\} \cong \{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_k}{2^k}|(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_k,...) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\}$ is clear when we show no two different sequences of {$x_i$} yield equal sums.  (Which is straightforward to show).

We have to then show $\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_k}{2^k}|x_k \in \{0,1\}\}= [0,1]$ which .... is tedious but the completeness/least upper bound property of the reals leads directly to that.

And finally we must show $[0,1] \cong \mathbb R$ with is a standard result.  $(0,1) \cong \mathbb R$ via $x \rightarrow \arctan x$.  And with tedium we can show for infinite $S$ and finite $I$ that $|S| = |S \cup I|$.

And that does it.  Although as no-one ever asked to show $P(\mathbb N)$ was uncountable, I could have skipped Cantor's diagonal altogether and just gone to the postscript.

But if I had done that, the clear parallel between $A \subset \mathbb N$ and $x \in [0,1]$ wouldn't have been immediately clear.

Comment: Uncountable does not imply "the same cardinality as the reals".

Comment: Good point.  But then we can define for A $\subset $ N the map $f (A) = \sum_j v/2^j $ where $v = 1$ if $j \in A $ and $v=0$ if not.  Then.... oh, wait.... ;)

Comment: The point is that your answer does not address the question *at all*.

Comment: I would say I incorrectly misread the question but I wouldn't say this doesn't answer the question "at all".  It describes a mapping from P(N) to {0,1}^N and most analyst texts show |{0,1}^N| = |R|.

Comment: Now it's better.