# Unclear use of big union symbol in proof of a fixed point theorem

Tags: notation, set-theory, fixed-point-theorems

I'm looking at a proof given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1885829/666263

Specifically, this section:

> **III. Lemma ([Knaster–Tarski Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem)). If a function $\varphi:P(A)\to P(A)$ satisfies the condition
>   $$X\subseteq Y\implies\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(Y)$$
>   for all $X,Y\subseteq A,$ then $\varphi(S)=S$ for some $S\subseteq A.$**
>
> **Proof.** Let $\mathcal F=\{X:X\subseteq\varphi(X)\}$ and let $S=\bigcup\mathcal F.$ First note that, if $X\in\mathcal F,$ then $X\subseteq S$ and $X\subseteq\varphi(X)\subseteq\varphi(S).$ Since every member of $\mathcal F$ is a subset of $\varphi(S),$ it follows that $S=\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq\varphi(S),$ that is, $S\in\mathcal F.$ From $S\in\mathcal F$ it follows that $\varphi(S)\in\mathcal F,$ whence $\varphi(S)\subseteq S,$ and so $\varphi(S)=S.$

In the proof, the author writes $\mathcal F=\{X:X\subseteq\varphi(X)\}$ and then $S=\bigcup\mathcal F$. and i'm unclear whether $S = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} A$ or something else.
In other words, i'm asking if given a set of sets $\mathcal{F}, $ $\bigcup\mathcal F$ is the union of all elements of $\mathcal{F}$ or something else?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the relevant portion of the proof you're asking about. Making your problem more self-contained will make answering easier: when potential answerers have to click through to other images/posts/links, it reduces the likelihood they'll spend time on your question.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal{F}$ is a set consisting of subsets of $A$. The notation $S=\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ is intended to express the union of all of these subsets of $A$ as a subset of $A$.

Comment: Actually that would not be a better way to write it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you're right, that isn't quite it. The original notation does not satisfy me, though - do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Getting used to the notation? :-)

Comment: I knew there was a reason I leave the set stuff to folks like you :P

Comment: I mean, why would you use $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$ and not $a_0+\dots+a_n$? And why would you also end up writing $\sum a_i$ when the index set is clear from context?

Comment: Well, the original issue in this case was that what was going on wasn't clear to the asker. I think saying "take the union of all the sets in $\mathcal{F}$" is probably the easiest way to clear this up if the notation isn't clear.

Comment: I have no qualms with your answer as a whole, just that this is notation to get used.