# How to properly read this proposition?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

I'm reading this book (OK, Efe A. Real analysis with economic applications. Princeton University Press, 2007.) and in page 143 the author claim this proposition:
[image]

I don't know how to properly read the part after the equal sign of U, can someone rephrase it in other words?

Comment: "$U$ is the union of all the elements of $\mathcal{O}$ contained in $U$".

Comment: There is no definition of $U$. $U$ is just some arbitrary open subset of $X$, and according to this proposition, we can find some countable class $\mathcal O$ satisfying the statement given above.

Comment: how U can be the union of elements contained in itself? it is not redundant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unclear use of big union symbol in proof of a fixed point theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502454/unclear-use-of-big-union-symbol-in-proof-of-a-fixed-point-theorem)

Comment: It looks like the proposition is saying that each open set in $X$ is a union of sets belonging to $\mathscr{O}$.

Comment: i think that's the way of read it, Barry Cipra! something like "every subset O of U belongs to O' too"

Comment: Barry Cipra's comment is correct, but what Barry Cipra said is very different from "every subset O of U belongs to O' too"