# Quiestion about cardinality of powet set

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I was reading this post: [Cardinality of power set of $\mathbb N$ is equal to cardinality of $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885700/cardinality-of-power-set-of-mathbb-n-is-equal-to-cardinality-of-mathbb-r). Here, bof considered the function
$f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to\mathbb{R}$, where for all $S\subset \mathbb{N}$, $f(S)=\sum_{i\in S}10^{-i}$. ¿Why is $f$ inyective?

I tried to solve this. I suposse that there are $S,T\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i\in S}10^{-i}=f(S)=f(T)=\sum_{i\in T}10^{-i}$. If $S\neq T$, there is $k\in S-T$ or $k\in T-S$.
If $k\in S-T$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
f(S)&=&\sum_{i\in S}10^{-i}\\
&=&\sum_{i\in S-\{k\}}10^{-i}+10^{-k}\\
&>&\sum_{i\in S-\{k\}}10^{-i}\\
&=&\sum_{j\in T-\{k\}}10^{-i}\\
&=&\sum_{j\in T}10^{-i}=f(T)
\end{eqnarray}
Is true that $\sum_{i\in S-\{k\}}10^{-i}=\sum_{j\in T-\{k\}}10^{-i}$? I'm not sure. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885700/cardinality-of-power-set-of-mathbb-n-is-equal-to-cardinality-of-mathbb-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Angel No, it's a question about one of the proofs there. not an exact dupe.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I said "possibly".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Since $S \neq T$, there is a smallest $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $k$ belongs to one but not the other. WLOG, $k \in S \setminus T$. In that case, now we can write $$10^{-k} + \sum_{i \in S, i > k} 10^{-i} = \sum_{i \in T, i > k} 10^{-i}.$$
Check that the LHS is at least $10^{-k}$ whereas the maximum value that the RHS can take is...

Comment: My idea exactly but put nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much! Aryaman. I understand now.